# Are quests / Storyline shared between my characters in Diablo 3 (if within eligible level range)?

Tags: diablo-iii

This question is rather difficult to phrase.

I played a character to lvl 9, then left them alone.  Then I played a different character to 15, advancing further in the quests and storyline.

Today I logged into my old lvl 9 character, and all the quests I completed on Character 2 showed as completed and my next quest was way up in lvl 15sville.

Are storyline quests shared across characters? There's no way to have a character separate from that (aside from "going back" on Character 1 and "starting" at an earlier quest in the line)?

Comment: Is it possible you played multiplayer with someone else?  Then it might be possible.  If this was all single player, I don't believe this happens in the way you describe.

Answer (score 1):

No, they are not shared between characters.  Either you played a multiplayer game in which you were jumped forward to a later quest, or it is just a bug.  I've experienced this before where quests are marked as completed even when they shouldn't have been, and I've seen numerous other reports of it as well.  I wouldn't worry about it, you can use Change Quest to back up to wherever you want to be.